# Disabled ActiveDirectory Users from specific date with exclude list

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

i wrote a script that gonna disabled old users...
and i need to do an exclude list to it...
the exclude list should be .csv, with 3 columns "Name","SamaccountName","Reason"...
i'm kind of stuck with the exclude list filtering...
i tried to do -notmatch and -notcontains and nothing worked for me...
i even try to do a foreach with if but the same...

```
 Function Get-ADLockOldUsers {
param ()
begin{
    [datetime]$myDate = '01/01/1601 02:00:00'
    $colObj = @()
    $AllUsers = (Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties lastLogonTimestamp | ? {$_.Enabled} | Select-Object Name,SamAccountName,@{N="LastLogon";E={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}})
    $AllUsers = $AllUsers | ? {(Get-Date).AddDays(-30) -gt $_.LastLogon -and -not ($_.LastLogon -eq $myDate)}
}
process {
$AllUsers | % { 
        $obj = New-Object psobject
        $obj | Add-Member noteproperty 'Name' $_.Name -Force
        $obj | Add-Member noteproperty 'SamAccountName' $_.SamAccountName -Force
        $obj | Add-Member noteproperty 'LastLogon' $_.LastLogon -Force
        $obj | Add-Member noteproperty 'NeedDisabled' $true -Force
        $colObj += $obj
        }
}
end { return $colObj }
}

Function Set-ADLockUser {
param()
begin{
    if (Test-Path '.\excludeusers.csv') {
        $excludeUsers = Import-Csv '.\excludeusers.csv'
        $DUser = @()
        $colUsers = Get-ADLockOldUsers
        $colUsers | ? {$_.SamAccountName -notcontains $excludeUsers} | % {Set-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName -Enabled $false -WhatIf }
        }
    else { Write-Output "Error! excludeusers.csv cannot be found, stop script"; break }
    }
process { 
    }
end{}
}

Set-ADLockUser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string value can never contain an array, so

```
$_.SamAccountName -notcontains $excludeUsers
```

will always evaluate to `$true`. You need to reverse the check and make the reference an array of strings (the CSV import produces an array of custom objects). Selecting only the field `SamaccountName` from the imported CSV and switching the arguments should do what you want:

```
$excludeUsers = Import-Csv '.\excludeusers.csv' | % { $_.SamaccountName }
...
$colUsers | ? { $excludeUsers -notcontains $_.SamAccountName } | ...
```

---

As a side note, you could simplify the the code for finding obsolete accounts like this:

```
$myDate = Get-Date '01/01/1601 02:00:00'
$limit  = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)

$colObj = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * `
  | ? { $_.Enabled } `
  | select Name,SamAccountName,@{n="NeedDisabled";e={$true}},
      @{n="LastLogon";e={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}} `
  | ? { $limit -gt $_.LastLogon -and $_.LastLogon -ne $myDate }
```

Comment: That was just to be on the safe side, because some properties aren't included by default. The `select` statement filters the properties you actually need from the whole set.

Answer (score -1):

This is the final solution...

```
  <# 
    .Synopsis 
     Get All Users in the Domain and check the last logon Date
    .Example 
     Set-ADLockUser -ReportOnly:$true
     Get all users that didn't logon for a 30 days and write a report to the current directory
    .Example 
     Set-ADLockUser -ReportOnly:$false
     Get all users that didn't logon for a 30 days and disabled them
    .Description
     Get All Users in the Domain and check the last logon Date, and exclude some users from a list .\excludeusers.csv
    .Parameter ReportOnly 
     Specifies if the script is in reportmode or active mode if ReportOnly=$false all the relevant users will lock
    .Outputs 
     PSObject[] 
    .Notes 
     Name:   Set-ADLockUser 
     Author: Ohad Halali 
     Date:   14.07.2013 
    .Link 
  #> 
Function Get-ADLockOldUsers {
param ()
begin{
    [datetime]$myDate = '01/01/1601 02:00:00'
    $colObj = @()
    $AllUsers = (Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties lastLogonTimestamp | ? {$_.Enabled} | `
                Select Name,SamAccountName,@{N="LastLogon";E={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}}) | `
                ? {(Get-Date).AddDays(-30) -gt $_.LastLogon -and -not ($_.LastLogon -eq $myDate)}
}
process {
$AllUsers | % { 
        $obj = New-Object psobject
        $obj | Add-Member noteproperty 'Name' $_.Name -Force
        $obj | Add-Member noteproperty 'SamAccountName' $_.SamAccountName -Force
        $obj | Add-Member noteproperty 'LastLogon' $_.LastLogon -Force
        $obj | Add-Member noteproperty 'NeedDisabled' $true -Force
        $colObj += $obj
        }
}
end { return $colObj }
}

Function Set-ADLockUser {
param([bool]$ReportOnly=$true)
begin{
    if (Test-Path '.\excludeusers.csv') {
        $excludeUsers = Import-Csv '.\excludeusers.csv'
        $colUsers = Get-ADLockOldUsers | ? {$excludeUsers.SamAccountName -notcontains $_.SamAccountName}
        if ($ReportOnly) {
            $colUsers | Export-Csv '.\Report.csv' -NoClobber -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII -Force
            }
        else {
                $colUsers.SamAccountName | Set-ADUser -SamAccountName $_ -Enabled:$False -Replace @{info="Disabled after no login for 30 days (Script)"} -WhatIf
            }
        }
    else { Write-Output "Error! excludeusers.csv cannot be found, stop script"; break }
    }
process {}
end{}
}

Set-ADLockUser
```